# this is my code and my problem is: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java

public boolean findCongDan(String socancuoc) throws SQLException {
CongDan congdan = new CongDan();

```
    openDatabase();
    
    String sqlFind = "Find From CongDan Where SoCanCuoc = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sqlFind); 
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()) {
        stmt.setString(1, socancuoc);
        stmt.setString(2, congdan.getHoTen());            
        stmt.setString(3, congdan.getDiaChi());    
        stmt.setString(4, congdan.getGioiTinh());  
        stmt.setString(5, congdan.getNgaySinh());  
        stmt.setString(6, congdan.getDanToc());  
        stmt.setString(7, congdan.getTonGiao()); 
        
        stmt.close();
        }
    closeDatabase();
    int rowFind = stmt.executeUpdate();
    
    return rowFind>0;
}
```

Comment: Move `stmt.setString(1, socancuoc);` **before** `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide parameters for your query before executing it. You have to call `setString` on your prepared statement before calling `executeQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Every ? in the query string needs to be provided in the `stmt.executeQuery()`:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("search value");
```

effectively making the query like this:

```
Find From CongDan Where SoCanCuoc = 'search value';
```